# Codeigniter form validation on pop up login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use the form validation library on CodeIgniter on my pop up login window, when an error occurs I want to echo the validation errors in my pop up window.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view("menu");
    $this->load->view("content");
}
```

Because when the error occurs the views reload and the pop up window is closing
Is there a way to manage to have my pop up window opened when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

For your return from the form validation you could do something like this:

```
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 0,
            'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array()
        ]));

        return false;
    }
```

It will return your for requirements along with the errors, then in jQuery you would do something like this:

```
<!-- Javascript POST -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#login_error").hide();
        // Check the login form, so your form name may vary
        $("#login_form").submit(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var postData = $(this).serialize();

            // Grab the post data
            $.post(url, postData, function(o) { 
                if (o.result == 1) {
                    // Redirect for successful loging
                    window.location.href = '<?=site_url('pageheretogoto')?>';
                } else {

                $("#login_error").show(); // Show your popup window, I'm showing a div here of #login-error
                var output = '<ul>'; // Format the output into a list
                for (var key in o.error) {
                    var value = o.error[key];
                    output += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                }
                output += '</ul>';
                $("#login").html(output); // Modify the html output for the #login div which you would probably change it to your pop-up.
                }

            }, 'json');

        });

    });
</script>
```

You would need to make sure you modify the div names but this should give you a great starting point to do it 1) without a page refresh and 2) placing the content where you want it. The example isn't using a pop up window or modal box but you could easily adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery.validate() and match the same set of rules, the way you want it to work would be too complicated. You would have to submit the form, refresh the page, then open the popup if there are errors. It's kinda... wrong.

Reference: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try your suggestion right now!